# How to pass a wildcard for the file name in a Powershell script

Tags: powershell

Hi i am writing a batch script to replace some strings in an ascii file and then save the file. My requirement however needs me to work with multiple files with a wildcard as the file name.

Currently, I have arrived at this iteration of the script:

```
powershell -Command "$path = Convert-Path c:\AutoPart\det.hbegyv.PALS1250.* | (gc $path) | -replace 'ZVA ','ZAPS' | Out-File $path - Force -Encoding Ascii"
```

How can I improve my script to accept wildcard as the file name?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing a batch-script to run Powershell? Why not just create a .ps1 script directly?

I believe this should do what you want if saved as a .ps1. You can of course surround it with quotation marks, prepend powershell and place it in a .bat file if you want.

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\AutoPart\det.hbegyv.PALS1250.*" | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_) -replace 'ZVA','ZAPS' | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

**Update:**

If you must run it from a .cmd or .bat and can't use a .ps1 you would probably need to format it this way:

```
Powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Get-ChildItem 'c:\AutoPart\det.hbegyv.PALS1250.*' | ForEach-Object {(Get-Content $_) -replace 'ZVA','ZAPS' | Set-Content $_.FullName}"
```

Notice that it's all one line and I've added the `-NoProfile`, `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` and `-Command` switches to the Powershell call.

I've also replaced the double quotes around the path for Get-ChildItem with single quotes as they would conflict with the double quotes around the entire Powershell command.

Comment: Hi Thanks Laage.  I did what you suggested, added quotation marks and save script as PALS125_Script.bat but it is not working.                                                                             "Get-ChildItem "c:\AutoPart\det.hbegyv.PALS1250.*" | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_) -replace 'ZVA ','ZAPS' | Set-Content $_.FullName
}"

Comment: Hi, I've added an update to the my answer, which works for me if a .ps1 is not a viable option.

Comment: Hi Laage, actually I am new to ps but after playing the script with your input I manage to get it working now!  Thank you very much!

Comment: That's great. If this worked for you, I would appreciate if if you accepted the answer as well.